# I have Detail method in Home controller and I want no ajax call access Detail method in controller how its possible in mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I need to create one Method in controller and protect like no any ajax call work on this method in mvc ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways of doing it.

1. If you want to prevent it from accessing the URL directly or through AJAX but access it through only the controller or view, you can use `[ChildActionOnly]` attribute.
2. If you want to declare a method and not use it as an Action method, you could have the attribute `[NonAction]` or make the method private. Note that this will result in the method not being visible to Http